# Queue Iterator with Java

Tags: java, iterator, queue

I'm trying to use a queue to store a set amount of data and I want to be able to iterate through it. I made a new queue with a specific type and I am having a problem with the iterator. Whenever I call iterator.next() I have a type mismatch. "Can't convert from void to motionEvent". motionEvent is the type that I am storing. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is snippet of the code.

```
    Queue<motionEvent> queue = new LinkedList<motionEvent>();

    ....

    Iterator it = (Iterator) queue.iterator();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        motionEvent temp = it.next();
     //THis is where I am having the problem with mismatch type

    }
```

Here is the motionEvent Class:

```
public class motionEvent
{
private long time;
private int positionX;
private int positionY;

public motionEvent()
{
    time = 0;
    positionX = 0;
    positionY = 0;
}

public motionEvent(long time_in, int positionX_in, int positionY_in)
{
    time = time_in;

    positionX = positionX_in;
    positionY = positionY_in;
}

public long getTime()
{
    return time;
}

public int[] getPosition()
{
    int[] temp = new int[]{positionX, positionY};
    return temp;
}


}
```

Comment: Why do you cast `queue.iterator()` (which returns Iterator<motionEvent> I guess) to `Iterator`? That would cause it.next() to be not of type `motionEvent` (however I am not sure why it returns `Void` and not Object).

Comment: Are you talking about a runtime or compile time problem? If it is a runtime problem you need to show how you instantiate and add the elements.

Comment: It is a compile problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not cast to the raw type:

```
Iterator<MotionEvent> it = queue.iterator();
```

Comment: I tried this, I am getting a "Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The type HTMLDocument.Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <motionEvent>" error. Is there something that I have to add to the motionEvent class?

Comment: Nvm, this works. I had imported the wrong Iterator. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well normally items of different type cannot be directly assigned by one to another. Also voids cannot be assigned, try finding the methods of iteration. Also your motionEvent is of its own type so it must be added indirectly threw a set or convertion.

Comment: It is not a different type though. The queue contains motionEvents and I am trying to pull out a motionEvent.

Comment: Event though the queue contains motion events the iterator is a void as stated by the exception report.